# How to change behaviour of Enter key in QML Dialog?

Tags: python, dialog, qml, pyqt5, pyside2

The following code creates a dialog. There is inconsistent behaviour happening between pressing the "Enter" key and hitting the "OK" button. When the enter key is pressed on changing a field, only that field is updated. When the OK button is pressed, both are updated (which is preferred). How can I override the Enter key to do the reasonable thing here?

What I would really like, is if the enter key sends the updated field back to the application without closing the dialog, since I would like to control something from within the dialog.

view.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3


Item {
    Dialog {
        id: thedialog
        ColumnLayout {
            TextField {
                id: numberField
                onAccepted: {
                    backend.number = text
                }
            }
            TextField {
                id: textField
                onAccepted: {
                    backend.text = text
                }
            }
        }

        onButtonClicked: {
            backend.number = numberField.text
            backend.text = textField.text
        }

    }
    Button {
        text: "Show Dialog"
        onClicked: thedialog.open()
    }
}
```

main.py

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Property
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtQuickWidgets import QQuickWidget

class Backend(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._number = 0
        self._text = ""

    def getNumber(self):
        return self._number

    def setNumber(self, number):
        print(f"Setting number to: {number}")
        self._number = number
        self.notifyNumber.emit()

    notifyNumber = Signal()

    number = Property(float, getNumber, setNumber, notify=notifyNumber)

    def getText(self):
        return self._text

    def setText(self, text):
        print(f"Setting text to: {text}")
        self._text = text
        self.notifyText.emit()

    notifyText = Signal()

    text = Property(str, getText, setText, notify=notifyText)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()

    quick = QQuickWidget()
    backend = Backend()
    quick.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)
    quick.setSource("view.qml")

    window.setCentralWidget(quick)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attached Keys API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    QtObject {
        id: backend
        property real number
        property string text
    }

    Dialog {
        id: thedialog

        function doSomeStuffBeforeClosingTheDialog() {
            backend.number = parseFloat(numberField.text)
            backend.text = textField.text
            // Remove this if you do not want the dialog to close
            accept()
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            TextField {
                id: numberField
                onAccepted: backend.number = text

                Keys.onReturnPressed: thedialog.doSomeStuffBeforeClosingTheDialog()
            }
            TextField {
                id: textField
                onAccepted: backend.text = text

                Keys.onReturnPressed: thedialog.doSomeStuffBeforeClosingTheDialog()
            }
        }
    }
    Button {
        text: "Show Dialog"
        onClicked: thedialog.open()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed this works well enough (doesn't prevent Enter key altogether but works when text fields are in focus), but only for the Enter key in the centre of the keyboard. Can it be done for the Enter key on the numpad also?

Comment: I think it should just be a matter of adding another signal handler for the [enterPressed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#enterPressed-signal) signal: `Keys.onEnterPressed: thedialog.doSomeStuffBeforeClosingTheDialog()`

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this one as complete as I think it might be as close as I can get to what I'm after. If anyone knows how I can stop it from closing the dialog when I press enter and a TextField is not in focus, (so override enter key on the Dialog itself) that would be awesome too.

Comment: For me, the dialog doesn't close when I press enter without a text field having focus.

Comment: Weird. I noticed your code doesn't import QtQuick.Dialogs which I needed to do, and I am running a previous version to you, so maybe it?

Comment: Oh, I'm using Dialog from Qt Quick Controls 2, yeah. :) Dialog from Qt Quick Dialogs needs a separate import, but the newer one doesn't.